# I left the acknowledgment part in a double blind review paper submission, what can i do?

Tags: conference, paper-submission

I forgot to remove the acknowledgment when i submitted my paper to a conference with a double-blind review conference. And the acceptance notice would be 4 months from now. I think it's useless to contact the chairs asking for re-submission as in top conferences they are not flexible. 
But if i can be sure that the paper will be rejected then i can send to to another upcoming conference in during that time. But i do not want to deliberately revoke my paper from the conference!
BTW, the acknowledgment part shows my affiliation.

Comment: Contact the organisers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Send an email to the conference program chair right away and ask. The better conferences will be honest with you, either way. The answer could be no revision, but then you could move on.

These mistakes happen.

Comment: Yes, a clear decision soon is the best for you and for the organisers. It's better than the reviewers finding this out and ultimately rejecting the paper on formal reason after having had read through it first.

Comment: I do no know how serious is that nowadays, as in most cases the reviewer can find the authors based on the relevant works he has done, or even the arxiv version! So maybe they do not consider it seriously unless i insist on "hey! please reject me!". But your point it right as well!

Comment: Based on the suggestion, i contacted them and they replaced the submitted version with another identical version only without the acknowledgement. Apparently they were more reasonable than i though! Now everyone is happy again! ;)